# When java arguments are reassigned

Tags: java

```
public void method1 (String a)
{
   a = a + "xyz";
   method2 (a);
}
```

Is there any ambiguity about which "a" is passed to method2 - the original argument or the new local version?

Comment: There is only one a to be passed. No "new a" is created but the existing one is reassigned a new value.

Comment: It's poor style to reassign parameters though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"a" is variable name for a reference, in the method you are changing that reference to reference a new object, so when you call `method2` it copies the new reference. Some basic illustration below.

```
 method1Caller(){
   a1 ---> "s"
   method(a1) // copies a1 reference
 }

 method(a1){ //a1 points to "s" at this point
 a = a + "xyz"; //changing reference
 a ---> "sxyz"
 method2(a); // copies a which reference "sxyz"
 }
```

Note that "a" in the method1Caller will still be pointing to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any ambiguity about which "a" is passed to method2

No ambiguity. There is only one instance of String `a` in `method1`.

> the original argument or the new local version?

String `a` will be appended with "xyz" to form a new String object and it will be passed to `method2`.

Your code is essentially similar to:

```
public void method1 (String a)
{
   method2 (a+"xyz");
}
```

String is immutable, so you can rest assure that the "original" string that was passed into `method1` will not be affected.

Comment: "There is only one instance of String in method1." - incorrect

Comment: @ACV I meant by String - `a`.